# X11 Based Tools for Embedded Linux ARM Development

Tags: c++, ide, c, swift, arm

I'm looking for *X11 capable* software development tools which can be used for embedded Linux development directly on the target ARM hardware.

Desired target languages and architectures include:

- Target Boards: NVIDIA Jetson, Raspberry Pi, BeagleBone
- Architectures:  `aarch64`, `ARMv7/8` 32bit, `ARMv6` 32bit
- Languages: C/C++, [Swift](https://github.com/uraimo/buildSwiftOnARM), Python
- License: open source preferred

The goal is to identify ARM-base X11 such that tools so that GUI interations are possible without requiring a full remote desktop session.

For example, [gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) `ssh -X user@hostname -C gedit &` provides a source code text editor with syntax highlighting. However, [Qt for Linux/X11](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux.html) is for `x86_64` and not ARM.

*Note: The scope of tools for this question are ones where the application can reliably use X11 forwarding to run remotely on the target **without any requirement for a remote desktop session**.*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Both `Netbeans` and `Eclipse` are available on my Raspbian `stretch` running Pi.  Not sure which versions though.

That said, running such a full IDE (esp. one written in Java) on a limited power SoC or embedded board will likely leave a lot to be desired.

What I recommend instead is to use `geany` - basically a fantastic text editor.  With a console built in. And configurable buttons labled "compile" "build" and "execute" that are file extension aware (ie, "build" on a file named `foo.cpp` can run `g++ ...` and for `Foo.java` it  can run `javac ....`)

Both Free and free, cross platform as well as cross-architecture.

My only complaint is a lack of `git` integration...

Comment: Good to know that `geany` offers efficient performance relative to the Java IDEs. Any observation or comment on the use `geany` with an `ssh -X` X11 application forwarding sesson on headless ARM devices? ... so that a remote desktop session is not needed?

Comment: @l--marcl - works fine.  Any Linux GUI app should have no issues being exported to a remote display.